# Bootstrap popover with angular data -binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to show a bootstrap popover using angular js `{{}}` i.e. *data binding*

My popover is looking like,

```
<a href="#" class="noUnderline" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover"  data-placement="left" data-content = "{{helpSrv.helpInfo{{['singleFil'+field.displayName + 'MobTooltipId']}}}}" >
```

But it gives an error from angular js.
When evaluated it should look like `data-content="{{helpSrv.helpInfo['singleFilArchitectureMobTooltipId']}}"`

`helpSrv` is a service under which `helpInfo` looks like 
`this.helpInfo = {
'singleFilArchitectureMobTooltipId' = 'some text'
}`

and that 'some text' would eventually be my `data-content`. 
When I use `data-content="helpSrv.helpinfo['singleFilArchitectureMobTooltipId']"` it evaluates to `some text`. But I want it to be dynamic.
How to do that ??

Comment: Remove the curly brackets inside: `{{helpSrv.helpInfo['singleFil'+field.displayName + 'MobTooltipId']}}`

Comment: @devqon: It works. Thanks